# Write OrderdDict to Excel File

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I have a ordereddict with about 144 keys.I need to write this to a excel file in the same order i.e first key should come in first column and second in second column and so on.

```
csv_items = [('A', '08129'), ('B', '0'), ('C', '8'), ('D', '0'), ('E', '81'), ('F', '0'), ('E', '12'), ('G', '0'), ('H', '0'), ('I', '23'), ('L', '0'), ('K', '0')]
```

Am using python Xlsxwriter to write into excel file and following is the code used for that.

```
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook("sample.xlsx")
ws = wb.add_worksheet("Log Sheet")
first_row = 0
row = 1
for player in csv_items:
    for _key, _value in player.items():
        print row, player.items()
        col = data_excel.index(_key)
        ws.write(first_row, col, _key)
        ws.write(row, col, _value)
    row += 1  # enter the next row
        # print 'row', row, first_row
wb.close()
```

After writing to excel file order of column in excel file is as following,
C,D,A etc.Its not in same order presented in OrderDict.

How to sort the rearrange the columns as per the above dictionary order.

Comment: Is csv_items ordered dict? if yes I don't think so

Comment: @NikhilParmar yes csv_items is ordereddict in list

Comment: You say that `csv_items` is an ordereddict, but you show it as a list of tuples. Please update with the [exact code you are using](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).